# Discard columns from restore filelistonly procedure in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I've faced the next problem:

```
restore filelistonly from disk
```

returns different result set for different versions of MS SQL server. My script utilizes only few of them so I would like to select only those columns and discard all additional columns in order to be server version independent. Are there some possibilities available in SQL Server 2017?
    `OPENROWSET or OPENQUERY`

Don't work because FMTONLY is deprecated and both OPENROWSET and OPENQUERY now use sys.sp_describe_first_result_set before execution and result in error:

```
The metadata could not be determined because statement 'restore filelistonly from disk does not support metadata discovery.
```

Are there are any options that I missed?

Comment: Short of getting the server version and using a big `IF` statement that declares a table of the appropriate form (depending on version) that you use with `INSERT .. EXEC`, I don't think this can be done cleanly in T-SQL. And of course it will break on any version it doesn't know about. This is the sort of thing client code is much better equipped to handle.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the suggestion. I've considered this but this will still break if they add a new column in a new version of the server.

Comment: That's true, but fortunately new server versions with new columns don't appear all that often. The only foolproof way to do this is to use a script that's not written in T-SQL (but for example PowerShell); languages other than T-SQL can easily inspect the metadata of a result and use only the columns they want. Only T-SQL itself struggles with this, and then only for special statements like this.